# How remove yandex toolbar from my browser?

Tags: yandex

I want to remove yandex toolbar. I cant see it in my control panel, i also remove it in my registry, but I can see it. I also remove my cache, but it's still there.

[image]

here's the extensions of chrome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2QSv.png)

Comment: after how many months, i figure it out. it is only a bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
chrome://extensions/
```

and remove your toolbar.

Comment: i also tried it but it didn't appeared on the list of extension.

Comment: after how many months, i found out that it is only a bookmark.